# dataTable is wide than bootstrap span

Tags: ruby-on-rails, twitter-bootstrap, datatables

I have a Rails app where I'm using Bootstrap and jquery dataTables.

The dataTable is wider than the Bootstrap span set in the parent div. I would like the table to stay within the width of the span.

This is the first 2 lines of the view page:

```
<div class="span12">
  <table class="display table dataTable table-striped table-bordered table-condensed" id="dataTable1" >
```

Thanks for the help!

Comment: Are the columns too wide or what?

Comment: The width of the table is too wide.  dataTable automatically adjusts each column width.

Comment: You can specify the column widths in your datatable definition, if the auto width is too wide. I don't know how you've initialized the datatable, but in `'aoColumns': []`, you set 'sWidth' to a value on each column e.g. `'sWidth': '10%'`

Comment: I was hoping not to set each column width individually.  I just don't understand why the whole dataTable doesn't stay within it's parent div.

Comment: Have you tried to just put a width on the table? eg `<table style="width:600px"`

Comment: #markpsmith if you create an answer, I will accept it. Thanks for the help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As per request by @Reddirt to promote my comment to an answer...

Have you tried to just put a width on the table? eg:

```
<table style="width:600px"
```

Answer (score 0):

I ended up using this:

```
<div class="span12" style="width: 1100px;">
```